# How can I install multiple versions of the LabWindows Development Environment on the same machine?

Tags: labwindows, cvi

I develop software in LabWindows for multiple customers. Often it is the case that a customer is using a backlevel version of the CVI Run-Time Engine (RTE). When possible the customer is urged to upgrade to the latest, but when they can't I must build the software targeting the older RTE. LabWindows does not support compiling for previous versions of the RTE so the work-around is to install multiple versions of the LabWindows Development Environment, and compile using whichever matches the target RTE.

How can one install multiple versions on the same machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LabWindows installer will not permit an older version to be installed on a machine which already has a newer version on it. To get around this, the LabWindows Development Environment must always be installed in the order of oldest to newest, with the oldest version installed first.

Comment: Related information, Look at the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17198728/how-can-one-target-older-cvi-versions-during-build